# trying to understand a 4d array in python read in with osgeo gdal

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'd like to plot an array with the following dimensions: [3x3x180x360]

it's a 180x360 world map with 3 different opacity layers and 3 different pressure levels. Thus, I would like to plot the map with data of 1 opacity layer at one pressure level.

How can I access the array and plot the data using `plt.imshow()` for example?

Visualizing the data with panoply looks the following way:
[image]

````
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

granule = "CER_CldTypHist_GEO-MODIS_Edition4A_407408.202109.hdf"
hdf_file = gdal.Open(workdir_data + "/" + granule)
subDatasets = hdf_file.GetSubDatasets()
cld_amount_liq_md = gdal.Open(subDatasets[68][0]).ReadAsArray() # takes ~5min to read ...

# Shape of cld_amount_liq_md after ReadAsArray() is [64800, 3, 3] hence:
cld_amount_liq_md  = cld_amount_liq_md.reshape(180,360, 3, 3)

#filtering bad data:
cld_amount_liq_md[cld_amount_liq_md > 3.40E38] = np.nan

# Plotting -> how can I plot the data?
plt.imshow(cld_amount_liq_md[?,?,?] ,cmap ="jet")```
````

**Update:**
Here's additional info due to inputs from the comments:

1. How do I get the dimensions from the HDF file?

```
from osgeo import gdal

granule = "CER_CldTypHist_GEO-MODIS_Edition4A_407408.202109.hdf"
hdf_file = gdal.Open(workdir_data + "/" + granule)
subDatasets = hdf_file.GetSubDatasets()

j=0
for i in subDatasets:
    print(j, i[1]) # i[0] contains the path to subdataset, i[1] the info as seen in the screenshot
    j+=1
```

[image]

**Link to the HDF4 File**
Here's the link to the HDF4 File:
[CER_CldTypHist_GEO-MODIS_Edition4A_407408.202109.hdf](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/98ba49567c872341f353677956fc0bcf20220708114420/bceff2)

The full variable name of the subdataset is: Monthly_Day_Averages/Cloud_Properties_for_9_Cloud_Types_Monthly_Day/cld_amount_liq_md

Comment: "How can I access the array and plot the data using plt.imshow() for example?" Well, according to your understanding, *which part of the array* do you want to use? What is the *rule that tells you* the part to use? Would you be able to answer a question like this for an array with fewer dimensions? Do you know how to do this sort of thing with Numpy's multidimensional arrays *at all*? Exactly *what is the point of confusion*?

Comment: Also: make sure you understand the **order** of the dimensions. You describe the problem like "I'd like to plot an array with the following dimensions: [3x3x180x360]", but the code says `cld_amount_liq_md.reshape(180,360, 3, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Yes, I'm familiar with up to 3d arrays. The answer by @PieterGeelen confirmed my understanding. Yet,  it's not plotting as expected and as I'm used to. Getting the dimension for that dataset in the HDF file results in: [3x3x180x360]. After ReadAsArray() the shape is: [64800, 3, 3], hence the .reshape() command. I presume the reshaping is causing the problem, so I'll check it again step by step.

Comment: "Getting the dimension for that dataset in the HDF file results in: [3x3x180x360]" What exactly does this mean? How do you "get the dimension[s]", and how exactly is this information reported to you?

Comment: I've added the info to the question.

Comment: I wonder whether the gdal.ReadAsArray() function doesn't work properly for 4d arrays? The actual data isn't grouped in layers. Printing the arrays returns always the same numbers in a 3x3 array. Where's the actual data...?

Comment: If you provide an [mcve] e.g. one that reads in a link from some public HDF file with a similar format, I can answer this. Shouldn't be too hard. Either combine the pressure level and opacity into an RGBA value, or maybe a library can display it for you - a web search turns up h5py.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, unfortunately  it's not very informativ: (https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Dataset-class.html)

Comment: @Joooeey thanks for the comment. I've added a link to the hdf file. h5py will not work since my files are in HDF4. I've come accros a ```MDArrayReadAsArray``` function but haven't found out how to use it yet.. (https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal_array-module.html).

Comment: Your question is still far from an MCVE. You can read in the file with `urllib.urlopen` and extract the specific dataset. Your MCVE should run on any machine with an internet connection and Python (+ required modules) without issues until the last line with `imshow`. That makes it easy for us to focus on the question and not deal with other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

As expected, .ReadAsArray() does not work for multidimensional arrays.

The HDF4 file needs to be opened and processed the following way:

```
hdf_file = gdal.OpenEx(workdir_data + "/" + granule, gdal.OF_MULTIDIM_RASTER)
rootGroup = ds.GetRootGroup()
op = rootGroup.OpenGroup('scientific_datasets')
ds3 = op.OpenMDArray('cld_amount_liq_md')
data = ds3.ReadAsArray(buffer_datatype = gdal.ExtendedDataType.Create(gdal.GDT_Float64))
```

or in a shorter version:

```
ds = gdal.OpenEx(workdir_data + "/" + granule, gdal.OF_MULTIDIM_RASTER)
rootGroup = ds.GetRootGroup()
op = rootGroup.OpenGroup(rootGroup.GetGroupNames()[0]).OpenMDArray('cld_amount_liq_md').ReadAsArray(buffer_datatype = gdal.ExtendedDataType.Create(gdal.GDT_Float64))
```

After that the 4D-Array can be accessed and plotted the usual way:

```
#op's shape is: [3, 3, 180, 360]
plt.imshow(op[1,1,:,:],cmap ="jet")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

so a simple index should work, indexing on the first opacity and first presure level:

```
plt.imshow(cld_amount_liq_md[1, 1, :, :] ,cmap ="jet")
```

Please check what the shape is of the index, so maybe something like adding `.ravel()` can make sense to remove the extra dimensions.

```
plt.imshow(cld_amount_liq_md[1, 1, :, :].ravel() ,cmap ="jet")
```